# Removal of one HDD (2TB) from a storage pool gives me warnings (2TB+8TB+8TB SHR)

Tags: synology

I have 3 drives in Storage Pool 1 and want to remove one of the drives (2TB). I went to Storage Manager and deactivate the small drive and now gives me warnings. I plan to later add another 8TB but in the mean time just keep the two.

Drive config: 2TB+8TB+8TB SHR

Is deactivating the correct way and then what do I have to do to remove the warnings and only keep the 2 drive configuration?

I would opt to just remove and rebuild the storage pool 1 but all the synology is installed on it.

[image]

Comment: It probably was using RAID5 for 2TB parts and RAID1 for the remaining space on 8TB disks; when you removed the 2TB disk, the RAID5 part become degraded and this produces a warning.

Answer (score 0):

When you deactivated your 2TB drive, you degraded your storage pool. You should replace that deactivated drive as soon as possible to reduce the risk of data loss.

It would have been best to have kept the 2TB drive in the storage pool until you have a replacement on hand.

Until you replace the drive, you are running without redundancy, putting your data at risk.